# Temperature conversion (loop 5 times)

Tags: python

This is not part of the script: As I execute my code, everything runs smooth until the loop ends. Then, there is an error with 'end' being defined?? Why is this so, and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

```
# convert.py
#   A program to convert Celsius temps to Fahrenheit by: Samuel Sikes

print("This program converts Celsius to Farenheit")

def main():

    for i in range(5):
        celsius = eval(input("What is the Celsius temperature? "))
        fahrenheit = 9/5 * celsius + 32
        print("The temperature is", fahrenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit.")

    end

main()
```

Comment: what is end supposed to be? You should **not** use  `eval(input` either, cast to int or float depending on want you want

Comment: Python doesn't end blocks with a closing keyword. Remove that `end`.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete "end."  It's not Python syntax.

Comment: presuming the OP does not have end defined somewhere and is trying to access it in another function